# Entering special characters fails in Oracle table

Tags: sql, unicode, oracle11g, special-characters

I need to test if my application is reading special characters from the database and displaying them in exactly the same way. For this, I need to populate the database table with all special characters available. However, I am not sure how I can specify the special characters in the sql insert query. Can anyone please guide me to an example where I can insert a special character in the query? For simplicity sake, suppose the table is a City table with Area and Avg_Temperature being the 2 columns. If I need to insert the degree (celcius/farhenheit) symbol in Avg_Temperature column, how should I write the query?

---

**[Edit on 1/9/2012 at 2:50PM EST]**As per Justin Cave's suggestion below, I did following analysis:

Table: `create table city(area number, avg_temperature nvarchar2(10));`

Date: `insert into city values (1100, '10◦C');`

```
Query:
select dump(avg_temperature, 1010) from city where area = 1100;

O/P
DUMP(AVG_TEMPERATURE,1010)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
----------------------------------------------------------
Typ=1 Len=8 CharacterSet=AL16UTF16: 0,49,0,48,0,191,0,67                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              

Query
select value$ from sys.props$ where name='NLS_CHARACTERSET';

O/P
VALUE$
----------------
WE8MSWIN1252

Query:
select value$ from sys.props$ where name='NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET';

O/P
----------------
AL16UTF16
```

It seems that the insert does mess up the special characters as Justin Cave suggested. But I am not able to understand why this is happening? Can anyone please provide related suggestion?

Comment: What is the database character set?  What is the national character set?  Are you loading the data into a VARCHAR2 column?  Or an NVARCHAR2 column?  Does the character exist in the database character set?

Comment: @JustinCave: Database characterset: WE8MSWIN1252 ; National CS: AL16UTF16. I would be loading the data into NVARCHAR2. I am not sure if the character exists in the character set! I am told to build the applcn in an existing database and so I wanted to be sure that I do not run into these issues. Can you please guide me where I can find out the allowed characters for the characterset mentioned above

Comment: @darkie15: you should not have problems when using UTF16 that includes almost all characters known to mankind. The real problem is the transfer from client to the server (and all the intermediate steps, like import files, web pages, emails, ...)

Comment: @darkie15 - Wikipedia, among others, has a character map for the Windows-1252 character set http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252 that will show you which characters are valid in the database character set.

Comment: Ok. So I just added a row in the database table containing a degree symbol i.e. `INSERT INTO CITY(Area, Avg_Temparature) VALUES (1100, '10◦C');` SQL Client being used is Oracle SQL Developer. On viewing the table contents, the value is displayed incorrectly for the temperature column with degree symbol. I checked the encoding of SQL Developer and it is UTF8. Is it that the database encoding is messing up while entering the special characters?

Comment: @JustinCave: Can you please help me out with my query above?

Comment: @darkie15 - What does `SELECT dump( avg_temperature, 1013 ) FROM city WHERE area = 1100` return?

Comment: @JustinCave: Thank you for replying back. The result of executing the same query is `Typ=1 Len=10 CharacterSet=AL16UTF16: 0,83,0,72,0,89,0,191,0,67`. I did not understand the significance of the value 1013. The oracle documentation only mentions 1008, 1010, 1016 and 1017

Comment: @darkie15 - Apologies, that was a typo.  I meant 1016, not 1013.  The character is being corrupted during the insert.  Can you explain exactly what you mean when you said "I checked the encoding of SQL Developer and it is UTF8"?

Comment: @JustinCave: Rerunning the query with argument 1016 gives me: `Typ=1 Len=10 CharacterSet=AL16UTF16: 0,53,0,48,0,59,0,bf,0,43`. How did you figure out the data is corrupt. With respect to encoding for SQL Developer, I mentioned it because running `SELECT *` query on the same table in Putty->SQL*Plus could not render the special characters properly. However, when we changed the Unicode Encoding to UTF-8 for Putty and logged into SQL*Plus again to run `SELECT *` query, we were able to view the special characters. Not sure if this helps in any way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should not store the symbol as part of your column. That requires you to declare the column as `VARCHAR` which will give you **lots** of problems in the long run (e.g. you cannot sum() on them, you cannot avg() on them and so on)

You should store the unit in which the temperature was taken in a second column (e.g. 1 = celcius and 2 = fahrenheit) and translate this when displaying the data in the frontend. If you really want to store the symbol, declare the units columns as CHAR(1):

```
CREATE TABLE readings
(
    area               number(22),
    avg_temperature    number(10,3),
    units              varchar(2)
)
```

Then you can insert it as follows:

```
INSERT INTO readings 
 (area, avg_temperature, units)
VALUES 
 (1000, 12.3, '°C');
```

But again: I would not recommend to store the actual symbol. Store only the code!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but the problem is that the degree symbol is only an example. We are actually receiving this data from the client and it contains just about many special characters (including degree symbol). I am not sure if your solution fits to the real scenario.

Comment: So what is the real problem then? I showed you an example on how to insert the degree symbol.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to know what the database character set is.  Then you need to know what character set your "client" connection is using.  Life is always easier if these are the same.

If your databse is utf-8 and your client is utf-8 then you don't need to do any character escaping you can just use the utf-8 encoding for the desired character.

In your example the degree character is unicode codepoint u+00b0.

In utf-8 this is a two-byte sequence:  x'c2', x'b0'.

Comment: "Is it that the database encoding is messing up while entering the special characters?" Not exactly. According to your information above you are using the Windows-1252 character set encoding at the database level -- this character set consists of a maximum of 256 characters 0-127 being the standard ASCII set and 128-255 as defined by the codepage defintion. If your SQLDEVELOPER client is set to use UTF-8 encoding then it uses the UNICODE character set (many thousands of characters) with 1-byte, 2-byte, 3-byte or 4-byte encodings (depends on the character).

Comment: continued -- standard ASCII characters (0-127) are THE SAME in UNICODE (and are encoded as single bytes in UTF-8) as in the Windows-1252 character set so that's why everything works until you attempt to store a non-ASCII character. Switch your SQLDeveloper "Environment" encoding to windows-1252 -- you should be fine then because both the Database and the Client will be encoding characters the same way.  Ultimately, you need to ask your customer what encoding their data is in to ensure the database will support it.